# Umbraco only loads main/default master page and nothing else

Tags: asp.net, umbraco

I have some strange behaviour with Umbraco. After upgrading from 4.6 to 6.1.3, something seems to be wrong. Whatever page i click, the page loads only the 'outer content' / the default masterpage. The template that is selected for that specific page seems to be ignored completely.

I also tried to force the sub/nested masterpage to cause an error, but nothing happens. So it seems that it really isn't loaded.

Also when i try to select another template for that page, i still get the default / main masterpage, and nothing else. Even when creating a new page which uses a new masterpage, i still get the same result!!

So it seems that Umbraco just always loads my default masterpage, and that it..

Has anyone had this same experience? Or does anyone know where to look or what to do to find out what causes this problem?

Comment: Did you upgrade directly from 4.6 to 6.1.3? Or did you do the recommended two-step upgrade?

Comment: Can't tell without seeing your template code

Comment: Solved the problem myself. See answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, after lot's of researching and debugging. 
It turned out that somehow, Visual Studio had added a **default.aspx.cs** (codebehind file) to the default.aspx Umbraco gave me. This was what was causing all strange behaviour. After deleting this file, everything started working as it did before.

Comment: remove the tag but no output from child views, only the master is loading.